# Getting unexpected token for table_info for sqlite in ionicframework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, sqlite

I have used PRAGMA table_info to get the info of a particular table in the ionic framework but when i try to compile it i am getting the error as unexpected token for table_info.But when i tried the same query in DB browser(SQLite) i got the result.

I have used the CordovaSQLite plugin in my app.

```
PRAGMA table_info(contacts)
```

Comment: Apparently, Ionic does not allow PRAGMAs.

Comment: @CL. then how could i know the info about the table in ionic and why PRAGMAs are not allowed in ionic

Comment: @Nidhinkumar can you show some code , how you are calling this

Answer (score 0):

Try to give it in a query like this

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(self.db, 'PRAGMA table_info(category)').then(function (res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
      if (res.rows.item(i).name === 'is_deleted') {
        hasISDeleted = true;
      }
    }
    if (hasISDeleted === true) {
      $log.log('going to update category');
      var query = 'UPDATE category SET is_deleted = ? WHERE is_deleted IS NULL';
      prom = $cordovaSQLite.execute(self.db, query, ['false']).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        $log.log('category response', res);
      });
      $log.log('category prom', prom);
      proms.push(prom);
      $q.all(proms).then(function () {
        defer.resolve('Sucess');
      });
    } else {
      defer.resolve('Sucess');
    }
  });
```

Hope it will work.